# Ajax & Forms Question (Looking for Resources)

Tags: ajax, forms

I have a select form. After a user selects option A, B, or C I need to use Ajax to load another form based on the users decision.

I'm not asking for someone to program this for me. I am just wondering, does anyone know of any good resources to help me accomplish this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which part is a problem for you - capturing user's input or loading the external resource?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [JQuery](http://jquery.com) samples. You can accomplish the result in different ways (included tabs)